# Function with matplotlib object in subplot

Tags: function, matplotlib, subplot

I am creating piecharts in python, due to customizations, I code pie chart in a function . 
Now, I want to create a subplot where each one of its plot is the output of the function. However, the resulting piechart has blank spaces, how do I get rid of extra blank spaces? 
Please refer the code below, am I missing something?

```
a= pd.DataFrame([1,2,3])

def test(x):
    x.plot.pie(y=0);



fig= plt.figure();  # create a figure object

fig.add_subplot(1, 2, 1);  # create an axes object in the figure
test(a)


fig.add_subplot(1, 2, 2) ; # create an axes object in the figure
test(a)
```

How can I put the plots into rights position in subplots ?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specify the axes when plotting:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 2)  

def test(x, ax):
    x.plot.pie(y=0, ax=ax)

test(a, ax[0])
test(a, ax[1])
```